# How yo configure a bucket in S3 to send emails when someone is downloading a file?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-iam

I have been looking the way to configure push notifications as an alert notificator in my S3 portal, I had tried with SNS notifications, I created a notification topic, I created the policy associated with the SNS ARN  in my bucket, but the policy generator doesn't recognize the SNS ARN link.... honestly I dont know how to do this and i need help. I just want to recibe emails when someone login in to IAM login web page and send emails when an IAM user download a file.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to trigger an event when a user downloads an object from Amazon S3. Events are only generated when a new object is added or an object is lost.

See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

If you wish to send a notification when somebody accesses a file, you will need to handle the download request yourself. That is, the user will need to use a URL that accesses your own application, which then sends the email and provides the file to the user.

Alternatively, you could use **Amazon S3 logging** to view activity on your bucket. You could periodically scan the log and then send an email based upon the contents of the log file(s).